# What's the biggest grocery delivery service in Vancouver?

Tags: canada, shopping

I'm trying to check out how life works in Vancouver and it seems that there isn't a proper grocery delivery service that handles regular/non-organic food. [Yelp lists a few stores](https://www.yelp.ca/search?find_desc=grocery+delivery&find_loc=Vancouver%2C+BC) but they all look overpriced and the selection is limited.

Do people in Vancouver still mostly shop offline for groceries? Or am I just bad at Googling stuff in Canada?

Comment: "shop offline for groceries" - I have to admit, this expression made me laugh, once I figured out what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest and cheapest one is called [Save On Foods](https://shop.saveonfoods.com/store/CE241126/#/landing). They block IP addresses from outside of North America, which is why I couldn't find it before.

An alternative for organic products is [SPUD](https://www.spud.ca/).